# Cannot import csv file using neo4j-admin

Tags: neo4j

Hello i am trying to import csv file using neo4j-admin tool but i am receiving this error `graph.db' already contains a database`

Does this mean that i need to create new database every new import ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`neo4j-admin import` is only for creating a new db, it cannot be used to add to an existing db, so you would need to delete your graph.db folder prior to import.

You'll need to use an alternate means, like a [LOAD CSV query](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/) if you want to add into an existing graph.

Comment: i want to add a huge csv file so i prefer to use a batch import

Comment: In that case use [PERIODIC COMMIT](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) when using LOAD CSV